# Social-Link block not loading html on page with custom theme

Tags: theme-development, html, block-editor

When I use the Gutenburg Editor to add Social Links to my page it does not load the html on to the page. it shows the standard wordpress commenting (as shown below) but no html below it

```
<!--wp:social-links {"size":"has-huge-icon-size","align":"center","className":"is-style-logos-only"} -->
<ul class="wp-block-social-links aligncenter has-huge-icon-size is-style-logos-only">
<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"wordpress.com","service":"wordpress"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"amazon.com","service":"amazon"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"amazon.com","service":"amazon"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"wordpress.com","service":"wordpress"} /-->
</ul>
```

From my research the best reason for this I could find was a conflict with word presses font-awesome install, but after disabling all styling and plugins the social links still won't load. I have used Font-Awesome's conflict resolve javascript and that returns no conflict error, I have also tried enabling debugging mode in WordPress but that returns no conflict errors either.

Further more if I activate one of the default WordPress themes it loads the social links fine, so I am unsure what about the custom theme that is blocking the loading of the Social-Links

Can anyone help me determine the error or other possible methods of debugging to find out why it won't load the social-link html

Comment: How are you outputting page content in your template? It looks like you might not be properly using the `the_content()` function.

Comment: I am outputting content by getting the post object via

$post = get_post();

then outputting it via

$post->post_content;

the fact that the social links work when using a default theme is the kicker

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to output content. You're supposed to use `the_content()`. That will fix the issue.

Comment: thank you that fixed it! how to I flag your post as the answer and give you all the accolades?